# Apache2 can't run xvfb-run on ubuntu 14.04 server

Tags: django, apache, ubuntu, x11, xvfb

I have a Django project.

I'am using xvfb on ubuntu 14.04 server with selenium and firefox to generate pdf from html.

Below is the code sample which is inside a python script.

```
cmd = 'xvfb-run -a python path/to/script.py'
subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

When I run it through django shell, it's working fine and pdfs are genearted on the server.

But when I run it via apache2, it's creating some never ending processes probably deadlocks and apache2 is giving time out repsonse.

Apache2 mayn't use 3rd party programs which is xvfb here.

Should I integrate xvfb with apache2 somehow?